# Trace of Frobenius Morphism for Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am reading a paper on elliptic curve cryptography. In the [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/145.pdf) (Section 4), the authors claim that when the characteristic of the field is represented as
$$p=a^2+|D|b^2\\
\\
or\\
p=\frac{|D|+1}{4}a^2+|D|ab+|D|b^2,$$

then the trace of the Frobenius morphism can be written as
$$T=\pm 2a\\
\\
or\\
T=\pm a$$
respectively. I have tried in vain to prove this claim. Could anyone suggest a reference or a strategy to prove this result?

Comment: From your description it is not possible to help you as you do not explain the notations. What is $D$? The problem of course comes from the paper you link to. It does not explain this either. I suggest that you look at a better text on isogenies for elliptic curve over finite flieds. Like Kohel's thesis, cited as [6] in the linked paper.